# How to get height of horizontal scrollbar in a ListView

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me how can I get the height of horizontal scrollbar in ListView in C#? is it the same as the standard Horizontal scrollbar, if so is there any windows function that return that? basically I'm using ListView with OwnerDraw and want to know exactly how big is my client area which excludes ColumnHeader area and HorizontalScrollbar area.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.horizontalscrollbarheight.aspx)

Comment: Ok now also I need to calculate ColumnHeader's height too, I know that I can get the height using Bounds in DrawColumnHeader event handler but I need this value before that event handler gets executed.

Comment: ok I should also add that I don't want to add a temp item to the list and get the Items[0].Bounds.Top, so let's say the listview is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Control.ClientRectangle excludes scrollbars and borders.

```
    listView1.Scrollable = true;
    Console.WriteLine(listView1.ClientRectangle);
    Console.WriteLine(listView1.Size);
    listView1.Scrollable = false;

    Console.WriteLine(listView1.ClientRectangle);
    Console.WriteLine(listView1.Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

On .Net CF, where `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` and `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth` don't exist, some P/Invoke is required:

```
public sealed class Native
{
    public static Int32 GetVerticalScrollbarWidth()
    {
        return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
    }

    public Int32 GetHorizontalScrollbarHeight()
    {
        return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYHSCROLL);
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 GetSystemMetrics(Int32 index);

    public const Int32
        SM_CXVSCROLL = 2,
        SM_CYHSCROLL = 3;
}
```